# Opening Text file, in Vba, getting Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace

I have a system generated file with extensions 0001,0002 and so on. These files are editable in notepad as textfile. Below VBA Code was working but suddenly it is giving

> "error 1004 - Unable to get the replace property of the
>   worksheetfunction class".

I wrote the below code to read the file, Find & remove WHT and add spaces at a specific position from where WHT was found. Code was working fine but getting this error.

```
Sub RemoveWHTaddspaces() 
Dim Textfile as integer
Dim Filepath as String
Dim FileContent as String
Dim Check1 as integer
Dim Check2 as Integer

Filepath = Application.Getopenfilename()

Textfile=Freefile
Open FilePath For Input as Textfile
Filecontent = Input(LOF(Textfile), Textfile)
Close Textfile

Do
Check1=Instr(Filecontent, "WHT ")
Filecontent=Application.worksheetfunction.Replace(Filecontent,Check1,4,"")

Filecontent=Application.worksheetfunction.Replace(Filecontent,Check1+38,25,"                   
      ")
Check1=Instr(Filecontent, "WHT ")
Loop while Check1>0
Textfile = Freefile
Open Filepath For Output as Textfile
Print #Textfile, Filecontent
Close Textfile
Msgbox ("Done")
Reset

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you found a match.

Try this

```
    Check1 = InStr(FileContent, "WHT ")

    If Check1 > 0 Then '<~~~~~
        FileContent = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(FileContent, Check1, 4, "")

        FileContent = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(FileContent, Check1 + 38, 25, "      ")
        Check1 = InStr(FileContent, "WHT ")
    End if
```

Also you have an invalid character `&` in the name of your procedure..  `Sub RemoveWHT&addspaces()`. A typo I guess?

Comment: Yes the match is there. I have corrected the typo of & in sub name.

Comment: You will get the error if there is no match. I see that you are looking for a SPACE after "WHT". Are you sure it is a space and not some other unprintable character in the text file?

Comment: You may want to manually delete that space in the text file and inserting it again using spacebar?

Comment: Yes i have to remove the text with a space. There are many instances of the same so i cant delete the space and add it again.

Comment: Try it with one and see.

Comment: Like I mentioned, it is best to use `If Check1 > 0 Then`

Comment: Did it and added the If statement.. Still same error

Comment: Can I see your text file? You should not be getting that error.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot share the file or post any picture. It is a normal text file and the code was working fine in last week. Suddenly this error.